# Setting the MinimumLevel in Serilog: is it possible to use a wildcard/regex for the namespace?

Tags: regex, overriding, wildcard, serilog, log-level

Setting the MinimumLevel in Serilog: is it possible to use wildcards/regex the namespace ?

Let's assume that I have my own namespaces with different casing, which need both to be logged on Information.

- MyNameSpace
- MYNameSpace

Can this be done via the configuration like this?

```js
"SeriLog": {
    "MinimumLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Override": {
        "Default": "Warning",
        "MyNameSpace|MYNameSpace": "Information"
      }
    }
  }
```

Or is this only possible by specifying both?

```js
"SeriLog": {
    "MinimumLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Override": {
        "Default": "Warning",
        "MyNameSpace": "Information",
        "MYNameSpace": "Information"
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Just thinking out loud -  Given that c# is case sensitive and so are namespace names, you're referring to 2 different namespaces so does it not make sense that the second sample would be 'better'? Although i see that this can get confusing...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The minimum level override feature does **not** support wildcards/regex as of this writing. It only supports simple (case-sensitive) partial matching. [You can see how it works in the source code](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/blob/master/src/Serilog/Core/LevelOverrideMap.cs#L76-L77).

Declaring the two different namespaces as your second example is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

You can also exclude some log entries using Serilog.Expressions
https://github.com/serilog/serilog/issues/1786#issuecomment-1487933383

I.e. set the minimum level for `System.Net.Http.HttpClient` to allow Information though, but use `Filter.ByExcluding(...)` and e.g. an expression to exclude `SourceContext like 'System.Net.Http.HttpClient.%.LogicalHandler'`.